# How do i format cell value as date in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to output the data in my excel file in the web. One of the cells in the excel is formatted as date and returns like this when outputted:

```
A000001 |   John Doe      | DR | 41456 | 41465<--  // this should be date
A000002 |   Philip Moris  | CP | 41456 | 41465     // formatted as yyyy-mm-dd



require_once("controller/xls/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filer);
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) 
{
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
$highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
$highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
$nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;

echo '<table>';
for ($row = 5; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) 
{
echo '<tr>';
     for ($col = 1; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col)
     {
    $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
    $val = $cell->getValue();
    echo '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
     }
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
```

Is it unix time? If so, how do i format it when I'm using getCellByColumnAndRow? I will also  store this in mysql db. Tnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an Excel timestamp value, a float containing the number of days since 1/1/1900 (or 1/1/1904 if the spreadsheet file is set to  use the Mac calendar rather than the Windows calendar).

Using

```
$cell->getFormattedValue();
```

will return the value as a string formatted as a date according to the cells format mask.

Alternatively, you can convert the Excel float value to a unix timestamp or a PHP DateTime object using the `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP()` or `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject()` methods, and then using the appropriate PHP functions/methods to generate a string in whatever date format you prefer